# Google Drive Auth: Creating JWT signature from JSON version of private key

Tags: php, jwt, private-key, sign

I am having trouble creating a JWT for Google Drive authorization. 
The instruction is given in [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount).

```
<?php
//helper function
function base64url_encode($data) { 
return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
}

//Google's Documentation of Creating a JWT https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

$raw_key_data="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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\nVuiSVVML3jW4XUtf63V0/A==\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";   

$private_key = openssl_get_privatekey($raw_key_data);
if ($private_key === FALSE)
{
    error_log ("Unable to extract private key from raw key data: " . openssl_error_string());
};

print("$private_key\n");

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}

$jwtHeader = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
"alg" => "RS256",
"typ" => "JWT"
)));

//{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}
$now = time();
$jwtClaim = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
"iss" => "myService-account-id@mySite.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
"scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
"aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
"exp" => $now + 3600,
"iat" => $now
)));

//The base string for the signature: {Base64url encoded JSON header}.    {Base64url encoded JSON claim set}

openssl_sign(
$jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim,
$jwtSig,
$private_key,
"SHA256"
);

$jwtSign = base64url_encode($jwtSig);

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}.{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}.    {Base64url encoded signature}
$jwtAssertion = $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim.".".$jwtSig;
print("$jwtAssertion\n");

?>
```

When I run this code, I get `Resource id #4` followed by a nonsense signature. I even tried putting the private key in a file and reading from the file in which there is multiple lines (private key separated at `\n` ) but no success. I can't generate meaningful JWT signature from the private key. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

I have managed to solve this issue. Below is the updated code that reads the JSON file downloaded from Google and creates an `assertion` with which one can then get access token from Google:

```
<?php
//helper function
function base64url_encode($data) { 
return rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($data), '+/', '-_'), '='); 
}

// Read the JSON credential file my-private-key.json download from Google
$private_key_file="my-private-key.json";
$json_file = file_get_contents($private_key_file);

$info = json_decode($json_file);
$private_key = $info->{'private_key'};

//{Base64url encoded JSON header}
$jwtHeader = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
"alg" => "RS256",
"typ" => "JWT"
)));

//{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}
$now = time();
$jwtClaim = base64url_encode(json_encode(array(
"iss" => $info->{'client_email'},
"scope" => "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
"aud" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
"exp" => $now + 3600,
"iat" => $now
)));

$data = $jwtHeader.".".$jwtClaim;

// Signature
$Sig = '';
openssl_sign($data,$Sig,$private_key,'SHA256');
$jwtSign = base64url_encode( $Sig  );


//{Base64url encoded JSON header}.{Base64url encoded JSON claim set}.{Base64url encoded signature}

$jwtAssertion = $data.".".$jwtSign;
echo "$jwtAssertion\n";
```

You may then test your code by communicating with Google Drive for example:

```
curl -d 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=YOUR-JWT-ASSERTION-BUILD-ABOVE' https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token
```